# My Lumia is not staying off when I turn it off

Tags: nokia-lumia-930

What do I do if my Lumia 930 is not staying off when I switch it off and when the screen locks it not opening up unless I put it to charge? What is causing my Lumia 930 to get hot?

Comment: It looks like you're asking about up to three different problems. Please describe each in a bit more detail.

Comment: When I switch off my Lumia it's automatically coming back on.                                                  The phone gets really hot especially when I'm online.                                                             Since it started giving problems to stay switched off I've had to turn off the automatic lock screen cuz when it locks it's not reopening unless I put it on the charger

Comment: Can you ask each problem as a separate question?

Comment: @Roxanne Addressing your first question: You're not plugging the phone in, are you? It will automatically turn on if you are charging it.

Answer (score 1):

I'm seeing three problems here. Please let me know if it is not the case.
1. Lumia phones switch on when charging. They cannot be switched off and put in charging at the same time.
2. Maybe your phone is getting hot because of apps running in the background or lock screen in peek or glance modes.
3. If you're not using the designated charger, your phone can behave abnormally and get hot while charging.

Let me know if something else is the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Windows Phones acts really weird when they are hot. I got almost the same issue with my Lumia 1020. If it got hot two often, the phone blocked itself and I had to wait that the battery was empty to use it again. What I did is avoiding it to be hot too often.